# Am I still vulnerable to SQL Injection? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, code-injection

I know most people would frown on this but before I knew about PDO statements and escape string I wasn't sure how i was supposed to prevent mysql injection.

I created a function that takes text and runs it through a filter. I'm wondering if it will really prevent sql injection or if they can get around it? My goal at the time was to allow users to be able to input text and be able to display it exactly as they entered it.

In addition to this I was also careful about making sure the user didn't have any more permissions on the database than what was needed. Whether I was using their input to update or insert a new row etc. But given that I hadn't would it still work?:

```
function filterInput($textToFilter)
{
    if ($textToFilter != null)
{



    //a = &#97;
    //e = &#101;
    //i = &#105;
    //o = &#111;
    //u  = &#117;

    //A = &#65;
    //E = &#69;
    //I = &#73;
    //O = &#79;
    //U = &#85;

    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('insert','ins&#101rt',$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('select','s&#101lect',$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('values','valu&#101s',$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('where','wher&#101',$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('order','ord&#101r',$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('into','int&#111',$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('drop','dr&#111p',$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('delete','delet&#101',$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('update','updat&#101',$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('set','s&#101t',$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('flush','fl&#117sh',$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace("'","&#39",$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('"',"&#34",$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace(';',"&#59",$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('>',"›",$textToFilter);
    $textToFilter = str_ireplace('<',"‹",$textToFilter);
$textToFilter = nl2br($textToFilter);
$filterInputOutput = $textToFilter;
return $filterInputOutput;  
}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're safe against an ASCII or Binary attack.

Comment: Also do you want to change `"` to its HTML entity.  Transforming is not  the same as escaping.

Comment: Does anyone know a simple website or something that explains how to use PDO? I'm pretty new to sql and php in general and am just teaching myself. I've tried looking for simple examples and everything seems to be a lot of complex code to go through.

Comment: the whole point of using PDO is that you can use Prepared statements, and then you don't need to escape your SQL strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitively "yes", because str_ireplace is not encoding safe (see [infos](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)).

And also "yes" because you forgot "truncate", "grant", "create", and so on.

The best way is to forget it and move to [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: This was months ago but you're right prepared statements are the way to go. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Since you're trying to roll your own "filter" function - the standard response is "yes, you are". it is very difficult to write "safe" code, and you're basically trying to reinvent the wheel, and doing so in a bad way.

Why are you going to all of this (pointless) trouble when you could just as well do:

```
$safe_text = mysql_real_escape_string($badtext);
```

(or whatever escape function your DB library provides) and let the database do all of the hard work for you?

Comment: Agreed, though even `mysql_real_escape_string` is discouraged with introduction of PDO.

Comment: Some people get saddled with horrible legacy PHP applications written by those that follow the w3schools style of *laisez-faire* programming. Baby steps.

Comment: pdo is prefered, but mysql_*() Is still far easier for one-liner throwaway examples. PDO's too 'bloated' code-wise for quick examples.

Comment: -1 because mysql_xxx() functions are considered obsolete and strongly recommended not to be used, and even if they weren't you don't want to use this in conjunction with PDO because `mysql_real_escape_string` requires a `mysql_connect` connection. just wrong all round. not sure how it got so many votes.

Comment: Even for "throwaway examples", **DO NOT USE** `mysql_query`. It promotes dangerous habits and sets a very bad example.

Comment: @tadman: mysql_query promotes nothing. it does exactly what you tell it to. It's not mysql_query's fault that it's far too easy for beginners to write bad code. That's PHP's fault in general, not a specific function.

Comment: PHP is trying to phase out `mysql_query`, which as you can imagine is a nearly insurmountable task given the attitude of people like you that insist on using it constantly. You shouldn't be using it. Period. If you are, you better have a very good reason, and it being "easy" is not one of them. Using `mysql_query` properly is significantly harder than using `mysqli` with placeholders. If you want to demonstrate a query, don't even bother to frame it in terms of PHP. It's not necessary. Let the person asking the question use it as they will.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing is best left to the experts. Do not attempt to roll your own. You should immediately patch this function to the much safer:

```
function filterInput($textToFilter)
{
    return mysql_real_escape_string($textToFilter);
}
```

Later you can get around to removing all references to `filterInput` and replace it with `mysql_real_escape_string`. A subsequent step would be to stop using `mysql_query` altogether as it's exceptionally dangerous. Switching to `mysqli` or PDO provides significant benefits, especially since you can use SQL placeholders to do the escaping for you, avoiding simple mistakes that could cost you dearly.